# How can I speed up a Java Spring response?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have a Spring controller for returning an object to a webapp. But the object takes too much time while it is being created, because it requires loading data from a database and performing some calculations with it.

I use Hibernate JPA, I dont have configured a cache, I dont have beans-config.xml because I use java based annotations for configurations my Spring system.

My goal is to speed up this processes.

I see problem in my code, that is not connected Odd using "ORM magic" but now I decided to not save RAM but speed up this request (While I redesign this messy code).

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lab/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Algo14web  getPicksByLeague()
{
    Algo1DAO ad = new Algo1DAO();
    Algo14web al = new Algo14web(ad.getAlgo(1)); // Long task
    return al;   
}
```

Algo1DAO method getAlgo:

```
public Algo1 getAlgo(int aid){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Algo1.class);  
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",aid));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Algo1> results = criteria.list();
    if(results.size()<1)return null;
    return results.get(0);
}
```

Algo1 class:

```
@Entity
public class Algo1{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;
   @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
   private Date dateFrom;   // start counting from this date to past
   @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
   private Date dateTo;     // date for last count date
   @Column(length = 3)
   private int pointNumber; // total goal per match
   @Column(length = 3)
   private int historyDeep; // history tree deep
   private boolean ast;     // allow some teams

   @ManyToMany
   private List<Match_soccer> matches = new ArrayList<Match_soccer>();
   ....
```

Match_soccer class:

```
@Entity
public class Match_soccer extends Match{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int mid;

   @Transient
   private boolean win;

  @Transient
  private List<Odd> odds;

  @Transient
  private Odd odd;
  ...
```

Odd class:

```
@Entity
public class Odd {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int oid;

private int mid;

@Column(length = 40)
private String bookmaker;

@Column(length = 6)
private float size;

@Column(length = 5)
private float over;

@Column(length = 5)
private float under;

@Transient
private float sodd;
```

Controller return to web app json string (this string change only 4 times per day):

```
{"deep":1,"goalsLimit":1,
"matches":[{"start":1438952400000,"sport":null,"country":"Iran","league":"Persian gulf pro league","ht":"Gostaresh","at":"Tractor","hr":1,"ar":3,"status":"OK","beid":"WplksZ06","mid":25,"win":false,"odds":null,"odd":{"oid":2476,"mid":25,"bookmaker":"Betsafe","size":2.5,"over":2.4,"under":1.51,"sodd":1.51},"resSum":4},{"start":1438966800000,"sport":null,"country":"France","league":"Ligue 2","ht":"Brest","at":"Nimes","hr":2,"ar":0,"status":"OK","beid":"bebW2dfJ"...
```

Algo14web methods (use constructor):

```
private void setMatchesStatus(){
    OddDAO od = new OddDAO();
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
        matches.get(i).setWin(checkOrwin(matches.get(i).getResSum()));
        if(matches.get(i).isWin())win++;
        else lost++;

        List<Odd> odds = od.getBymid(matches.get(i).getMid());

        if(odds == null){
            System.out.println("Odds null");
            odds = Collector.getUOOdds(matches.get(i)); // long task
            System.out.println("Try insert odds size "+odds.size());
            if(odds.size() == 0){
                Odd odd = new Odd();
                odd.setMid(matches.get(i).getMid());
                odds.add(odd);
            }
            od.insertOdds(odds);
        }

        matches.get(i).setOdd(this.setBestOUodd(odds));
    }
    proc = Math.round(win/matches.size()*100);
}

private Odd setBestOUodd(List<Odd> odds){
    Odd bodd = null;
    for (Odd odd : odds) {
        if(odd.getSize() == limit){
            if(bodd == null || (getOddSize(bodd)<getOddSize(odd)))bodd = odd;
        }
    }
    if(bodd != null)
        bodd.setSodd(getOddSize(bodd));

    return bodd;
}
```

Somehow, it seems to me that the decision is `Spring Cache Abstraction`, but I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: This code provides very little hint of what you are trying to do. How many records are you fetching from the DB? How complex the algorithm is? I would add some more detail.

Comment: Somehow, it seems to me that the decision is Cache Abstraction, but I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: The first time you fetch rows from the database I would not expect the cache to be already populated, so there is very little that the Cache can do for you.

Comment: What about static method? because `Algo14web al` object is updating only 4 times per day?

Comment: Edgaras, you need to provide more details. It is very difficult to help you this way: are you using plain JDBC? JPA? Have you configured a cache? Have you thought about pre-fetching data so that when the request will hit, it will perform faster? What does your beans-config.xml look like?

Comment: I use Hibernate JPA, I dont have configured a cache, I dont have beans-config.xml because I use java based annotations for configurations my Spring system. No I dont thought about pre-fetching, because first time heard about it or maybe is guilty of my English skills.

Comment: My first impression is that your business logic code smells a lot. I bet there are hidden "ORM  magic"  SQL queries behind many of these calls, but even without that the code is messy. Throwing RAM real estate (that's what caching amounts to) at essentially inefficient code is not a solution but a lame workaround.

Comment: Thanks of answer, I see problem in my code, that is not connected `Odd` using "ORM magic" but now I decided to not save RAM but speed up this request (While I redesign this messy code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static Algo14web al;   

 @RequestMapping(value = "/lab/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Algo14web  getPicksByLeague()
    {
        if(this.al == null || time2update){
           Algo1DAO ad = new Algo1DAO();
           al = new Algo14web(ad.getAlgo(1)); // Long task
        }


        return al;   
    }
```